# Не работает do end в многострочном блоке lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем привет! У меня есть scope, который содержит следующий код:

```
    scope :tests_by_category, lambda { |category_name|
                              joins(:category)
                                .where(categories: { title: category_name }) 
                                .order(title: :desc)
                              }
```

В чем проблема: когда я хочу заменить фигурные скобки на do..end, конкретно:

```
lambda do |category_name|
  joins(:category)
  .where(categories: { title: category_name })
  .order(title: :desc)
end
```

lambda "теряет" блок, и выдает ошибку

[image: Описание ошибки]

Если написать не lambda, а ->(category_name) do...end, то все работает исправно, но в таком случае ругается рубокоп на то, что для многострочных блоков необходимо исправить -> на lambda. Подскажите, почему вообще лямбда "теряет" блок и можно ли это как-нибудь исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что приоритет оператора `do...end` ниже, чем `{}`. При использовании `do..end` блок "привязывается" к более левому оператору, то есть  мы получаем

```
scope(:tests_by_category, lambda) do |category_name|
  ...
end
```

Решение простое - скобки в нужном месте

```
scope :tests_by_category, (lambda do |category_name|
  ...
end)
```